# How create indexes for 2 fields to make their unique in collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have the entity with bson configuration

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }

[BsonElement("Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }

[BsonElement("PhoneNumber")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

[BsonElement("Role")]
public Role Role { get; set; }
```

In collection, I want to have a unique pair of fields `Email` and `Role`. However, how to realize it in core API, doesn't understand?

I found the property  `Indexes` and this property has `CreateOne` or `CreateMany` but how to configure that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have established your connection etc. and have the `collection` object...

You would call the Index Keys API you found (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/driver/definitions/#index-keys)

```cs
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<YourType>(
     new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<YourType>()
        .Ascending(x => x.Email)
        .Ascending(x => x.Role),
     new CreateIndexOptions() { <use if desired> });

collection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexModel);
```

You can also use the literal name such as `"Email"` (if you don't want or need type safety), of course do `Descending` instead of `Ascending`, and either omit or use the `CreateIndexOptions` (sounds like you'd want `Unique = true` here).